# how to consult a file on a ftp area in prolog?

Tags: ftp, prolog, swi-prolog

I try to consult a prolog file from a home server. See below.
So far, no success.

No urgency: I just upload the file locally to a PC where swi-prolog is installed and make the works from there. making the works remote would be a bit better.. = I could works from any PC in the house without uploading locally the file on a PC. 
I see the file with PCManFM 1.2.5 from any PC: perhaps this is a question of access because prolog should store in any way the user and pw in order to access automatically the file via ftp.

```
?- consult(ftp://192.168.178.1/EXCHANGE_02/transfer/uwr).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: consult(ft
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: p://192.168.178.1/EXCHANGE_02/transfer/uwr) . 
?- consult('ftp://192.168.178.1/EXCHANGE_02/transfer/uwr.pl').
ERROR: source_sink `'ftp://192.168.178.1/EXCHANGE_02/transfer/uwr.pl'' does not exist
?- consult("ftp://192.168.178.1/EXCHANGE_02/transfer/uwr.pl").
ERROR: source_sink `"ftp://192.168.178.1/EXCHANGE_02/transfer/uwr.pl"' does not exist
```

Comment: SWI-Prolog does not know FTP. You will need to download the file first using FTP then once it is local to the system can use consult.

Comment: Can you use HTTP instead? There is an HTTP client in SWI. Maybe you could upload over FTP and then get over HTTP. You still couldn't directly consult it though. Maybe you can use something like curl to download it first and then consult it?